# Get method not supported. Supports POST (not working for only MAC desktop Devices)

Tags: php, laravel, macos, methods, frameworks

fellow stack developers. The problem is that my laravel application that has been working fine suddenly started to give error on a specific route that the GET method is not supported. I searched for it found some solutions nothing worked. The code is 100% correct I made sure of that. The problem mainly occurs on only MAC desktop devices. It is working on android and even apple phones, but not on apple laptops. I am unable to find this specific issue. Please help me. I am sharing the codes below.

Route:

```
Route::post('/c/u/s/{userID}/{contractID}', 'ContractController@signContract1')->name('contractSigned1');
```

Controller:

```
public function signContract1($userID, $contractID) {
$request = new Request;
$user = User::where('id', $userID)->first();
$contract = Contract::where('id', $contractID)->first();
request()->validate([
    'user-signature' => 'required',
]);
$sign = request('user-signature');
// $contract->signed = $sign;
// $contract->save();

$image = $sign;  // your base64 encoded 
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = $contract->id.str_random(40).'.'.'png';
\File::put($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/storage/signs/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));

$contract->signed = 1;
$contract->userSign = $imageName;

$sign = request('user-contract');
$image = $sign;
$image = explode(";", $image)[1];
$image = explode(",", $image)[1];
// $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $sign);
// $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = $contract->id.str_random(40).'.'.'png';
$contract->contract = $imageName;

\File::put($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/storage/contracts/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));

$contract->save();

 $data = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'document' => $contract->contract,
    'email' => $contract->email,
);
\Mail::send('emails.newConByUser', $data, function($message) use ($data)
{
    $message->from('amit@ksbin.com', "KSBIN Contract Signed");
    $message->subject("Contract Signed");
    $message->to(['sajjadaslammm@gmail.com','insurance@ksbin.com']);
});

return back()->with('message','Contract Signed!');
```

View:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('contractSigned1',[ $user->id , $contract->id ]) }}" style="position: absolute;left: 33%;top:0">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" value="" id="myFile" name="user-contract">
                            <input type="hidden" value="" id="txt2" style="border-radius: 5px;" name="user-signature">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success confirm-sign-btn float-right d-block" value="Confirm Signing ⇒">
                        </form>
```

Comment: What is the full error message you're getting exactly? Also, you say it occurs on Macs...does the same happen in all browsers on those Macs, or just specific one HTTP doesn't really care about operating systems, but it's possible that some difference in the browser being used could potentially make a difference, although even then it's a bit odd. We need more specific info before we can have any hope of figuring it out

Comment: Why did you share a route defined with Route::post in your question, if you want to use GET?

Comment: @KurtFriars I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to work with post method. but I am receiving this error of get method not supported while I haven't used get anywhere.

Comment: @ADyson Only on MAC laptops and in every browser. I want to pass post method but it gives me error that get method is not supported while I haven't used any get method.

Comment: @TafseerHussain And you are using post, when receiving the error "GET method is not supported"?

Comment: @KurtFriars Yes. and only on MAC

Comment: This sounds totally bizarre. What is the full, exact error message and where exactly are you seeing it? A screenshot might be helpful if you can't describe it.

Comment: https://ibb.co/rkPFrwV
Here is the image and the route I have shared is the one where the error occurs. Yes its totally bizarre to me also why is this happening.

Comment: No, we need to see screenshot from the affected machine of when the error actually occurs. And please also look in the View Source of the browser affected, to check if the `<form` tag is rendered correctly. And watch the Network tool in the browser while the form is being submitted, and see if it really does make a GET request. Also, is there anything like JavaScript on the page which could be making requests or redirecting, or anything like that? This is going to need you to look in-depth on one of the affected machines.

Comment: Another thing - are all POST requests to your application affected by this, or only this single form? And have you tried, on an affected machine, to use a non-browser client (e.g. PostMan) to create a POST request to the route and see what happens? Also do these machines have anything else in common, e.g. all on one particular network or something? (I am wondering somehow about external factors messing with the request, perhaps. Bit of a shot in the dark but again, this is a totally bizarre situation - the O/S should not have any role in affecting what requests the browser makes.)

Comment: Yes I have check through postman,it works fine and also made sure that all the tags are properly completed. But definitely I'll look into the Network tool as I haven't done that yet. Not all ppst requests are affected only this single route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that url to accept the HTTP GET method, then you need to define that route in your routes file. So I am assuming you will want to change what you have to this:

```
Route::get('/c/u/s/{userID}/{contractID}', 'ContractController@signContract1')->name('contractSigned1');
```

Of course each url can support routes on all the different HTTP methods like so:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UsersController@get');
Route::post('user/{id}', 'UsersController@update');
Route::delete('user/{id}', 'UsersController@delete');
```

Comment: No, I am not using get method I am already using POST everywhere because I need the post method but on MAC laptops it keeps giving an error about GET method not allowed.

Comment: Can you add the code that is making an http request that produces the error to your question please.

Comment: You can see the code above. See the VIEW code, its using POST method and then see the route to which it is going that is also POST

Comment: OK, for MAC desktop can you add the HTTP headers of the request causing the issue?

Comment: https://ibb.co/sVHWtgS
Here are the headers and this is http://client.ksbin.com/c/u/s/79/9 where the exact error occurs.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I want the http request from the network tab of your chrome dev tools. I want to be sure your browser is in fact trying to make a GET request, on a form with POST defined as it's method.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is you have a different <form> defined on the same page and you forgot to </form>. Otherwise this is not a stackoverflow question, but a bug report for chrome on Mac.

Comment: No I double checked, there is another form but it has no errors. I'll send the http request detail from chrome dev tools. And its not on chrome its on Mac with every browser.

Comment: Share a link to the full html causing the error. This is either an extreme edge case that is somehow messing up chrome (unlikely), or you have something broken in your html, if you arent using ajax.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12xC8hRdf09pMVqBTXT_wm_wSSTTO5zUt?usp=sharing
Here you can view the HTML file(sign.blade.php), also the routes and controller file.
if u view it on editey, u can see the form on line 285

Comment: Can you please share the actual HTTP request as well. Will really help debug it. I am looking over the HTML now. If you don't know how to do that, please have chrome tools open while you click the submit button triggering the error, then go to the network tab, and find the offending request, and share all of the http headers.

Comment: https://ibb.co/23n22fy
Here is the screenshot of network and headers

Comment: So your browser IS posting the data

Comment: But nothing is being saved in the DB. This is some out of the world error 

Comment: dd($request) in your controller please?

Comment: Ok, from what you have sharedl, your browser IS POSTing, your application is receiving POST, so this is not a Mac issue. You will need to just manually debug this, no one else can solve this one for you.